# AIR Native extension read file with JAVA and handle it with Flash?

Tags: java, flash, file, arrays, air-native-extension

I have some files inside my app expansion file accessed with JAVA **APKExpansionSupport** provided by Google library. I can read files as **InputStream**, f.e. MP3, but I need to read this file on Flash side (to play it) and don't know how... 
My initial idea was to convert the **InputStream** to **FREByteArray** but I'm not sure if that's the way. Some hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it through IOUtils.toByteArray conversion (for synchronous solution).